# How to toggle both display+visibility with the usual jQuery methods?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've just implemented the default [Bootstrap theme](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/index.html) into my mobile site, only to find out that jQuery is unable to perform the simplier task: showing elements that have the *hidden* class. Unbelievable, but true.

The **extremely complex and problematic** hidden class is:

```
.hidden {
  display: none; /* jQuery smartly toggles this to block, well done! */
  visibility: hidden; /* But it forgets about this little attribute */
}
```

Currently *toggle(true)* and *show()* are changing only the *display* attribute, and not the *visibility* which remains hidden... Is there a workaround to toggle both display+visibility easily?

I rather not edit the bootstrap CSS just because jQuery is incapable of toggling both attributes in one sitting, this is very frustrating. How many people are developing jQuery, that not a single one of them ever used both  *visibility+display* attributes?

I use latest jQuery 1.11. Notice I also have to work with the **fadeToggle and all the usual animate methods** as well.

Comment: Why not just use `removeClass` or even `toggleClass`??

Comment: Because it would take endless hours to edit the code in every single script I call show/hide, toggle, fadeToggle methods. I assumed the purpose of jQuery was saving time, not the opposite...

Comment: jQuery is doing exactly as intended. By calling show() it sets `display: block`. It doesnt know anything about bootstrap `hidden` classes. Like anything else in jQuery, to remove custom multiple css properties in a class you use `removeClass` or `toggleClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing hidden Classic with .removeClass('hidden').

You could Write your own toggle with something like

```
if($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
   $(this).removeClass('hidden');
} else {
   $(this).addClass('hidden');
}
```